# IBM Watson conversion for dialog

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-dialog

I created one project with watson conversion.
Flow is like:(sorry i can't show my dialog flow but i will try to explain it)

(W:Watson,U:User)

U:what documents required for open account?
W: Name, Email, Contact. Can I open it for you?
U:Yes
W:Great, Please enter your Name.
U: XYZ
W: XYZ please enter your contact number.
U: 9999999999
W: XYZ, you are doing great please enter your email.
U: xyz@domain.com

```
now come to watson dialog part.

W:Great, Please enter your name.(i used " < ? input.text ?>" to take user input)
{
"context":{"name":"< ? input.text ?>"}
"output":{"text":"Great,Please enter your name."}
}

U:XYZ

W:XYZ please enter your contact number
{
"context":{"contact":"< ? input.text ?>"}
"output":{"text":"$name, Please enter your contact number"}
}

U:9999999999

W: XYZ, you are doing great please enter your email.
{
"context":{"email":"< ? input.text ?>"}
"output":{"text":"$name, you are doing great please enter your email."}
}

U: xyz@domain.com
```

This is my flow and it is working perfect when I run it inside the watson.
But when i am trying to run it from my own application then it takes only my name but not entered in loop means it is not taking other information.

```
reason is in json it pass:

{
"text":"XYZ"
}
```

but watson shows it's intent as irrelevant.

in my project i just want to pass user data from my application to watson and it display output as mention above.

```
is it support < ? input.text ?>...?
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question 

to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

For the part where Watson Conversation is giving intent as irrelevant, it is so because you be missing to send parameter conversation_id as context parameter.

You will get conversation_id in response and pass it in subsequest calls. If you do not pass that, then a new id will be generated everytime

```
//Extract converstaionId from first call 
String conversationId=msgResponse.getContext().get("conversation_id")

//Second call in which user gives his name
Map contextData=new HashMap();
context.put("conversation_id", conversationId); // conversationId will be in the response of previous call
```